# configure gpu on windows 10 in an anaconda environment using jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, gpu

What are the steps i need to follow so that
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
is able to find my gpu in a conda environment. I am using jupyter notebook.

I tried to install tenserflow-gpu but is not working

I have search in different places but everything seems to be too criptic for me and not up to date

Comment: Please be more specific. What is your setup, what kind of GPU do you have, which drivers do you have installed. Which steps have you taken to create your conda environment and start your jupyter notebook? Which guide have you tried to follow and which steps do you have trouble with?